# cannot match character in scala, expects Unit type

Tags: scala

This is my code:

```
val foo = "\\foo"
var escaped = ""
foo.foreach(c => {
  escaped += c match {
    case '_' => "\\_"
    case '\\' => "\\textbackslash{}"
    case '~' => "\\textasciitilde{}"
    case '^' => "\\textasciicircum{}"
    case '&' => "\\&"
    case '%' => "\\%"
    case '#' => "\\#"
    case '{' => "\\{"
    case '}' => "\\}"
    case ch => ch
  }
})
```

IntelliJ tells me that *Pattern type is incompatible with expected type, found: Char, required: Unit*. Why does this happen? `c` is obviously a Char, not a Unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are matching `escaped + char` to `'_'` etc. Do `match` inside `()` then concat with another variable.

```
val foo = "\\foo"
var escaped = ""

foo.foreach((char : Char) => {
  escaped = escaped + (char match {
    case '_' => "\\_"
    case '\\' => "\\textbackslash{}"
    case '~' => "\\textasciitilde{}"
    case '^' => "\\textasciicircum{}"
    case '&' => "\\&"
    case '%' => "\\%"
    case '#' => "\\#"
    case '{' => "\\{"
    case '}' => "\\}"
    case ch => ch
  })
})

println(escaped) //prints \textbackslash{}foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... the thing is that `foreach` on a `collection type` such as `List[A]` has following signature,

```
foreach(func: A => Unit): Unit
```

Which means that `foreach` wants a function of type `A => Unit` as parameter.

In this case, you have a `String`, and here `foreach` wants a function of type `Char => Unit` as parameter.

But look at the body of your function...

```
c => {
  escaped += c match {
    case '_' => ...
    ...
  }
}
```

What you actually have here is,

```
c => {
  (escaped += c) match {
    case '_' => ...
    ...
  }
}
```

And `(escaped += c)` is `Unit`. So to solve this all you have to use are proper parenthesis,

```
c => {
  escaped += (c match {
    case '_' => ...
    ...
  })
}
```

Also... you should avoid using this approach for building that string. You can just use a `map` to create your String instead of appending to it in a `foreach`

```
val foo = "\\foo"
val escaped = foo.map(c => c match {
  case '_' => "\\_"
  case '\\' => "\\textbackslash{}"
  case '~' => "\\textasciitilde{}"
  case '^' => "\\textasciicircum{}"
  case '&' => "\\&"
  case '%' => "\\%"
  case '#' => "\\#"
  case '{' => "\\{"
  case '}' => "\\}"
  case ch => "" + ch
}).mkString
```